# How to generate primary key (auto generated sequence) in apache cassandra

Tags: cassandra, key

I am new to cassandra, as i just started to learning it.

I did some sample application on it, but just bother **how to create a auto generated primary key for each record.**

Answer (score 1):

Use UUIDs instead of a sequence.